# How to make a circle sector menu in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

Well want to do menu like in image. Tried to with http://pmg.softwaretailoring.net/. But this code too hard for me to find and understand how to make this menu larger etc.

Are there some good solution for menu like this with easy to change ? :)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jesd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

A possible start point can be that:

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/dp2zg895/

You can also check this documentation for advanced shape design with css.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

**CSS**

```
#cone { 
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
```

}